# How can I search a wild card name in all subfolders?

Tags: shell, wildcards, recursive

How can I search a wild card name in all subfolders? What would be the equivalent of DOS command: `dir *pattern* /s` in *nix?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use `find`.  If, for example, you wanted to find all files and directories that had `abcd` in the filename, you could run:

```
find . -name '*abcd*'
```

Comment: Just adding a comment in case someone else will encounter the same confusion as I did: `-name` will look for a pattern that matches the filename, i.e. not the full path. So if you are looking for a file containing somewhere in its path the string `string1` followed by `string2` somewhere in the path you should use `find . -wholename "*string1*string2*"`.

Answer (score 20):

Zsh:

```
ls -ld -- **/*abcd*
```

Ksh93:

```
set -o globstar     # put this line in your ~/.kshrc
ls -ld -- **/*abcd*
```

Bash ≥4:

```
shopt -s globstar   # put this line in your ~/.bashrc
ls -ld -- **/*abcd*
```

Yash:

```
set -o extendedglob # put this line in your ~/.yashrc
ls -ld -- **/*abcd*
```

tcsh:

```
set globstar
ls -ld -- **/*abcd*
```

fish:

```
ls -ld -- **abcd*
```

(beware some of those shells will follow symlinks when descending the directory tree; some of those that don't like `zsh`, `yash` or `tcsh` have `***/*abcd*` to do it).

Portable (except to very old systems; OpenBSD took a long time but finally supports `exec … +` since 5.1):

```
find . -name '*abcd*' -exec ls -ld {} +
```

Not POSIX but works on *BSD, Linux, Cygwin, BusyBox:

```
find . -name '*abcd*' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld
```

Note that except in some BSDs, if no matching file is found, `ls -ld` will be run without arguments, so will list `.`. With some `xargs` implementations, you can use the `-r` option to work around that.

Comment: what does shopt -s globstar do??

Comment: @user2429920 http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Builtin-Index_bt_letter-S and click through to http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin then scroll down to `globstar`.